# ssh localhost, getting permission denied (password). (Windows 11)

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, windows-11, openssh

I am trying to ssh into my windows 11 machine from my mac but continue getting a Permission denied, please try again. After a couple of failed attempts I get username@localhost: Permission denied (password). I am able to ssh from my windows machine to my mac but not vice versa. Please help. I have pasted my sshd_config and the verbose output below.

I have WSL installed on my C drive and have been able to ssh username@localhost with my linux ssh instance. I tried to replicate the sshd_config from my linux ssh instance to my windows ssh instance to no avail.

**Updates**

- My local Windows account is linked with my Microsoft account.
- I am using my Windows password, not my pin when entering password.
- I am currently trying to ssh into my windows machine from my windows machine. Full command is `PS C:\Users\username> ssh -vvv machineName\username@localhost`
- Posted updated sshd_config and verbose output below.

**LINUX sshd_config**

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication no

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

**WINDOWS sshd_config**

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication no

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/administrators_authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

#Match Group administrators
#       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

**Verbose Output**

```
PS C:\Users\username> ssh -vvv machineName\username@localhost
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> 'C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> 'C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug3: failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'machineName\\username'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from localhost
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:uycZf1R9rAKihgAByNC0pbkxH8zxsTzA/KnEwsgQldk
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from localhost
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:JhaRB7T+Coj9p1VEOrGaENf+dc19YndDXL86u8lHcZ0 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:JhaRB7T+Coj9p1VEOrGaENf+dc19YndDXL86u8lHcZ0 agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
machineName\username@localhost's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
machineName\username@localhost's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
machineName\username@localhost's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
machineName\\username@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
PS C:\Users\username>
```

As you can see I enabled password authentication and disabled publicKey authentication for right now. I always run my terminal as administrator. I would hopefully like to switch to public key authentication once I get this password authentication problem resolved.

Comment: Is your local Windows account linked to a Microsoft Account. Instead of submitting a comment you should [edit] your question

Comment: My local Windows account is linked to my Microsoft account.

Comment: What username are you using? Based on the error your likely using the incorrect one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenSSH not accepting my login password](https://superuser.com/questions/1522466/openssh-not-accepting-my-login-password)

Comment: I didn't post my actual username for privacy concerns, but currently there is only one User on my C drive. When I do ```ssh localhost``` I am prompted to enter the password for the expected username@localhost.

Comment: If you’re connecting to your Windows machine why are you using localhost? Are you positive you have identified the correct username? It’s not that your Microsoft Account username.

Comment: Doing ```ssh machineName\username@localhost``` did not work.

Comment: I'm using localhost because I am on my Windows machine trying to ssh into itself, and yes I typed ```whoami``` in the terminal and copied the output into ```ssh machineName\username@localhost```

Comment: You ran `whoami` in which terminal? WEL has an independent user account that can have a different name. Also note you have to use your Microsoft account's password, not your PIN.

Comment: I ran whoami in my Windows terminal ```C:\Users\username>```. The current scenario that I am trying to work out is - I am in my windows machine and trying to ssh into the same windows machine with password authentication.

Comment: @sebdb - You said you were logging in from another machine, “I am trying to ssh into my windows 11 machine from my mac”, thus I assumed you were not specifying the correct username.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! It worked after changing the port number. Solution can be found more in depth here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/642588. Still unsure why this is... if somebody could further explain. Thank you everyone for the help.