# SSH connection fails for a Microsoft_account user on Windows 11 "windows authentication failed. error 1326"

Tags: ssh, windows-11, openssh, authentication

Update 18th July: After debugging for some time, I have found out that the issue is seen with Microsoft account only, not with a local account. I have updated the problem statement accordingly.

**Setup**

I have created 2 users on my Windows 11, namely naras and bhuva. naras is associated with a Microsoft account. Whereas, bhuva is a local account.

I have installed SSHD on Windows 11 and configured the SSHD as listed below following this [blog](https://theitbros.com/ssh-into-windows/):

1. Enabled Firewall rule to accept SSH connection
2. Added the following lines to sshd_config

```
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    SyslogFacility LOCAL0
    LogLevel Debug3
```

**Issue**

When I tried to establish a ssh connection either from my Windows system or from a remote Linux system using the Microsoft account naras, I am getting an error "windows authentication failed. error 1326" in sshd_config log and "Permission Denied" in the CLI.

```
C:\Windows\System32>whoami
computer1\naras

C:\ProgramData\ssh>ssh localhost
naras@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.

C:\Windows\System32>ssh naras@computer1
naras@computer1's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

**Problem Isolation**

The issue is not seen with the local account.

```
ssh bhuva@localhost
ssh bhuva@computer1
```

The sshd.log file is uploaded [here](https://github.com/bhuvanplus/logs/blob/main/sshd1.log).

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: My first instinct is that your Windows username isn’t naras

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. I have a Windows user "naras". I have trimmed the following result to fit in as a comment.

C:\Windows\System32>net user naras
User name                    naras
Full Name                    Bhuvan
...
Account active               Yes
Account expires              Never

Password expires             Never
Password required            Yes

Workstations allowed         All
User profile
Last logon                   17-07-2023 14:38:18

Logon hours allowed          All

Local Group Memberships      *Administrators       *Users
Global Group memberships     *None

Comment: Your inability to properly format that information was a hint you should have edited your question. Looking at the logs it appears at least one attempt was made on port 50538 despite the fact the service is running on port 22.

Comment: Hi @Ramhound, 
50538 is the client port. I am not trying to connect to it. By using the command `ssh localhost`, I am trying to connect to the server, which is listening on the default port 22. The log sshd.log also reveals the same details. 

`9300 2023-07-17 12:04:35.720 Connection from ::1 port 50538 on ::1 port 22`

Comment: I have also tried the command `ssh localhost -p 22` and faced the same issue. I have uploaded the [sshd.log](https://github.com/bhuvanplus/logs/blob/main/sshd2.log)

Comment: Just to clarify. This user is a local user on the server you’re attempting to connect to? The logs tell another story.

Comment: Yes, the user is a Microsoft Account. I use the same account to log in to my Windows server as well.

Comment: I created a new local user on the Windows server. I am able to establish a SSH connection. `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-LocalUser -Name naras, bhuva | Select-Object Name, PrincipalSource

Name   PrincipalSource
----   ---------------
naras MicrosoftAccount
bhuva            Local`

Comment: Coming back to my Windows account, whoami returns computer1\naras. I tried `ssh naras@computer1` as well. But the same issue. How to resolve the issue?

Comment: FYI; Your Window’s username is bhuva not naras. Using the same account is unnecessary nor is it actually the same account unless your using an an AD account

Comment: naras is the username associated with a Microsoft account. Whereas, I created a new local user called bhuva today to isolate the issue. The problem is still seen with the Microsoft account naras.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem. Please [edit] the question so it contains the necessary information to answer it.

Comment: So “ssh bhuva@localhost” is the wrong syntax for using a Windows account of the target machine. Despite the fact usernames are identical they very much are completely different users. Something like “computer1\naras@ computer1“ would be more accurate but without the client ssh verbose logs I cannot be certain. I also suspect the configuration file isn’t correct.

Comment: Make sure the user domain isn’t the same name as the username. Additionally, [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1522466/openssh-not-accepting-my-login-password) has helpful info. Suspect specifying the machine name will be enough since the domain name in the server logs is blank and it shouldn’t be

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound for all the help. I using a different domain name than the user name

Comment: I created a new Microsoft account to start afresh isolating the issue, and found that such an account has 2 passwords; online password and Windows pin (more details in [password_vs_pin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-why-pin-is-better-than-password)). I was using Windows pin for connecting to the SSH server and hence, it was failing "windows authentication failed. error 1326". We need to use the online password.

Comment: I tried the following formats and found them working irrespective of the type of account (local or Microsoft account). 
`C:\>whoami 
computer1\user1  

C:\>ssh localhost 
C:\>ssh user1@localhost 
C:\>ssh user1@computer1 
C:\>ssh user1@IP_address 
C:\>ssh computer1/user1@localhost 
C:\>ssh computer1\user1@localhost`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Microsoft account has 2 passwords; an online password and a Windows pin (more details in [password_vs_pin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-why-pin-is-better-than-password)). We need to use the online password.

If we use a Windows pin, it fails with an error "Permission denied, please try again" in the CLI and an error "windows authentication failed. error 1326" in the sshd logs.